# Another object with the same value for property identifierUris already exists

Tags: powershell, azure

I am running the setup.ps1 script at [this key vault sample project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-quickstart)
I executed it successfully once.

When I ran it again with different values except for the uri I got an error

```
New-AzureRmADApplication : Another object with the same value for property identifierUris already 
exists.
At C:\dev\key-vault-dotnet-quickstart\Setup.ps1:84 char:10
+ $adapp = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "$applicationName" -Ho ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzureRmADApplication], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.NewAzureADApplicationCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the identifier url needs to be unique